# in `lambda': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

```
scope :for_user, (lambda {|user_id| a = Follow.follows(user_id); Question.where{user_id.in(a.select{followed_id})}})
```

Gives me:

```
`lambda': tried to create Proc object without a block (ArgumentError)
```

I've read several questions without being able to fix the problem. I am relatively new to Ruby, and just getting started with Rails. I'm probably a bit over my head.

Comment: {} are only used for blocks or hashes... you've got them used for params for methods.

Comment: https://github.com/ernie/squeel Shows what I'm aiming for, they use curly braces.

Comment: what they're using is a "hash as a parameter" - but you'll notice that they don't chain extra stuff on the end. for that you'll generally need ().

eg: Thing.do_something {:a => :hash}
vs Thing.do_something({:a => :hash}).do_something_else({:another => :hash})

Comment: reading your link more clearly - yes, I can see what they say you can do. Can I just say - ick - I really don't like that syntax! I suspect your issue isn't in the extra {}s then,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the () around the lambda, though. How about you try building up from simple fist eg try:

```
scope :for_user, lambda {|user_id| Question.where(:user_id => user_id) }
```

just to see if it breaks/works... then add your actually-required functionality piece by piece until something breaks (or it all works)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone is trying to create a multiline lambda with the help of `do..end` block instead `{..}` it'll throw the same error.

> Not Recommended (will throw an error)

```rb
scope :for_user, lambda do |user_id|
  Question.where(user_id: user_id)
          .where(active: true)
  end
```

> Not Recommended (won't throw any error); instead use class methods

```rb
scope :for_user, lambda { |user_id|
  Question.where(user_id: user_id)
          .where(active: true)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and what worked for me was what Taryn East suggested: no ().

```
scope :event, lambda {|name| active.where(:key => name)}
```

That's how I got mine to work.